# Flagging a comment which links to a picture of the question

Tags: discussion, flagging

I've noticed a comment on a Question [How to stop unicode glyphs displaying as "emoji" in MS Word 2016](https://superuser.com/questions/1207541/how-to-stop-unicode-glyphs-displaying-as-emoji-in-ms-word-2016/1208736#1208736)

Which states

Note that those characters are still displayed as emoji on many platforms imgur.com/a/SVPJ9

The imgur link is a picture of the question so the link does not support the comment but I cant see the point either from adding to the question or some nefarious purpose.

I followed the link and ... so I flagged it as Non-constructive. Is this acceptable? Should I of done something different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading through *all* the comments, and the edit history it makes sense - basically the question rendered with what OP assumed to be B+W wingdingish charecters as emoji. See the rest of the comments, and the edits. At this point "obsolete" would be the correct flag.

Comment: So less "un-nice" ... thanks